# SQL how to sort text with numbers alphabetically, then numerically, with additional string to right

Tags: sql, vb.net, alphanumeric

Data stored in a `varchar` column looks like this:

```
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 2
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 23
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 138
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 256
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 250A
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 23 JT FAC
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 169 MASTER
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 214 INTERNAL
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 122 123 JT FAC
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 169 - INTERNAL
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 188 JT Sewer Plant
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 188 JT Water Plant
FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 214 MASTER DISTRICT
```

I'm trying to sort name first then if name contains number sort by number.

I am currently using this SQL code:

```
SELECT DistrictName
FROM Master
ORDER BY LEFT(DistrictName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', DistrictName + '0') - 1), LEN(DistrictName), DistrictName
```

It works well unless there is an additional string on the right side of the number. I would like the "23 JT FAC" to sort under "MUD 23" etc. So sorting name first, and if name contains a number sort the numbers. How could I modify this query to make this happen?

Thanks,

Comment: All of these start with `FORT BEND COUNTY MUD `. Is that true for all of them? If so, you can use a similar `ORDER BY`, but if not, then it gets complicated with string splicing.

Comment: And `order by 1` doesn't give you the sort you want? Just unclear based on your sample data, as all sample rows contain numbers. [Order by 1 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DaCIdb1-)

Comment: No the string in front of numbers can be anything and may or may not contain numbers

Comment: No order by 1 , 214 would be before 23. I want 2,23,214, etc, and if there is something after, then 2, 2 WP, 2 STP, 23, 23 STP, 214, 214A, 214 WP

Comment: While I guess possible doing this via SQL order by statement, fact that you've tagged this as vb.Net makes me think might be easier to execute the query un-ordered, then in the resulting dataset build the ordering where you've got a certain amount more flexibility with regular expressions and such.   That aside, would suggest there is a case for reviewing the table schema.  If that number is critical enough to ordering, I would think it should be stored as it's own attribute.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above query uses product specific functions.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio with data stored in SQL Server 13

Comment: Why is this question tagged VB.NET? If this is a pure SQL question then it is irrelevant what programming language you're executing the query from. If you want to sort the data in VB instead of in SQL then there is a Windows API function that will do it for you. It's the same Windows API function that File Explorer uses to sort file and folder names that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the number portion and cast as integer.

```
with my_data as (
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 2' as districtName union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 23' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 138' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 256' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 250A' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 23 JT FAC' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 169 MASTER' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 214 INTERNAL' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 122 123 JT FAC' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 169 - INTERNAL' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 188 JT Sewer Plant' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 188 JT Water Plant' union all
  select 'FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 214 MASTER DISTRICT'
  )
select districtName
from my_data
ORDER BY 
   LEFT(DistrictName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', DistrictName + '0') - 1), 
   cast(SUBSTRING(districtName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', districtName), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', districtName + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
                    districtName) + 1) as integer), 
   DistrictName
```

| districtName |
| --- |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 2 |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 23 |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 23 JT FAC |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 122 123 JT FAC |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 138 |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 169 - INTERNAL |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 169 MASTER |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 188 JT Sewer Plant |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 188 JT Water Plant |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 214 INTERNAL |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 214 MASTER DISTRICT |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 250A |
| FORT BEND COUNTY MUD 256 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qOGfveO5)